# Aerospike DB - lists/maps suitable at large sizes, under high write load?

Tags: aerospike

**Overview**

Aerospike list/map manipulations via UDFs are copy-on-write (one modification results in an entire rewrite). So, UDF-based appends become progressively expensive as the list/map size grows.

**List Manipulation by UDF, Test Results**

```
Time required to append 100 values to a list (each append persisted to disk independently)
Time measured at the Java client
Each result is the average of 10 measurements.
Initial list size = 1      -> 19.6ms
Initial list size = 1000   -> 43.4ms
Initial list size = 10000  -> 237.3ms
```

**Question**

Are lists/maps within a single record advisable at large (1000's of values, ~200kB total) sizes, under high write loads?

Comment: So one single object A got a relation to a few thousand objects of type B, correct (you can't shard/partition lists any more detailed..)? What is the network latency impact on a) your benchmark above and b) your later deployment? Is your namespace on SSD or is it IN-MEMORY?

Comment: Hi @ManuelArwedSchmidt. (1) Yes, several thousand values per user. (2) I get that a list is not sharded. This is OK. The main concern is the acceptability of write slow-down. (3) The client roundtrip latency is 7ms (if I set UDF to return immediately). The network latency while varying L remains the same. (4)  Please see question update for disk config

Comment: Did you take into account the list operations supported by the application-side client as well. Java client >= 3.1.8 and server >= 3.7.0 ?

Comment: Hi @RonenBotzer, I followed your suggestion. Client-side list operations do indeed perform much better (even at large sizes). Are those operations taking advantage of the Streaming Write Buffer? If so, that is very useful for hot/recently-accessed records.

Comment: The new client-api with 3.7.0+ server avoids the overhead of UDFs. The list datastructure is maintained and modified natively in memory. It gives the boost. (The UDFs also use streaming write buffer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aerospike server version 3.7.0 added support to manipulate lists directly using client API. Check the latest version of your favourite client language for support (Java 3.1.8+, Go 1.9.0+, C 3.1.25+). Such functionality to manipulate maps will follow.

Modifying the lists via native API is much more efficient than via UDFs. To start with, one need not pay the overhead of the UDF execution. If the data is in memory, the list will be maintained in memory in a format which is very efficient to perform the delta operations. It can easily sustain heavy read/write loads with less latency. Nevertheless, you should always benchmark for your workload.

Answer (score 2):

Single-record lists/maps can be efficiently manipulated via the **native client API**.

The test results in the question are based on using UDFs, which are slower because UDFs incur overhead (and perhaps cannot modify natively in memory?).

After Ronen's suggestion, I updated my client/server to get the new list API and wrote a new test using `com.aerospike.client.cdt.ListOperation`. The results of the new test are very fast regardless of list size.